# How to slice bytes from an array/list to get bit-sized entries instead?

Tags: python, arrays, list, list-manipulation

There are very long arrays with byte-sized entries. I want to make it so that each bit from every byte becomes its own array entry.

An example of what I want to do is to manipulate the following array:

```
[0b00001111, 0b01010101, 0b11110000]
```

to get this array:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I know that it is possible to do this via loops but I want to see whether there is a faster method (with less time complexity) first.

Comment: How "very long"? And do you have/want arrays or lists as inputs/outputs? If arrays: what kind of arrays?

Comment: What do you mean with *"time complexity"* in *"faster method (with less time complexity)"*?

Comment: And please show your code doing this via loops as a reference/baseline to compare to. Otherwise your request for something "faster" doesn't make sense. How are we supposed to test whether something is faster than X if we don't even have X?

Comment: If run-time efficiency is your primary concern, probably look into NumPy.

Answer (score 2):

So, I just want to point out, if performance really matters here, then probably, you would be best served by using numpy. You should start with an unsigned, 8-bit integer array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([0b00001111, 0b01010101, 0b11110000], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Then, you can do:

```
>>> np.unpackbits(arr)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

Or:

```
>>> np.unpackbits(arr).reshape(-1, 8)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Or perhaps more efficiently:

```
>>> np.unpackbits(arr[..., None], axis=1)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean by using loops is something like this:

```py
l = [0b00001111, 0b01010101, 0b11110000]
l_expanded = []

for n in l:
    l_expanded.extend(format(n, "08b"))

l_expanded = [int(n) for n in l_expanded]
print(l_expanded)
```

Output:

```py
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You could do this in one line like this:

```py
l = [0b00001111, 0b01010101, 0b11110000]
l = list(map(int, (b for num in l for b in format(num, "08b"))))
print(l)
```

But if speed is your biggest concern, you should probably use numpy:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0b00001111, 0b01010101, 0b11110000], dtype=np.uint8)
arr = np.unpackbits(arr)
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

You may also want to reshape your ndarray so that each number has its own row:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([0b00001111, 0b01010101, 0b11110000], dtype=np.uint8)
arr = np.unpackbits(arr).reshape(-1, 8)
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: why don't you use `map(int, iterable)`

Comment: @rioV8 I have edited my question, is that what you mean? Or can I use `map()` in some other way too?

Comment: it can be done in 1 line: `l = list(map(int, (b for num in l for b in format(num, "08b"))))`, but if he submits this the teacher knows he had some help

Comment: Ok thanks @rioV8

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark with 10^5 random bytes:

```
  3.89 ± 0.08 ms  bits_Kelly_juanpa
  5.84 ± 0.06 ms  bits_Kelly_4
  6.24 ± 0.16 ms  bits_Kelly_3
  6.44 ± 0.05 ms  bits_Kelly_2
  6.64 ± 0.06 ms  bits_Kelly_1
177.09 ± 1.33 ms  bits_sbottingota_1
177.28 ± 1.83 ms  bits_sbottingota_3
183.16 ± 2.39 ms  bits_sbottingota_2

Python: 3.11.4 (main, Sep  9 2023, 15:09:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]
```

Benchmark code:

```py
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
from random import shuffle
import numpy as np
import os
import sys


def bits_Kelly_1(a):
    bitss = [[*map(int, f'{i:08b}')] for i in range(256)]
    bits = []
    for byte in a:
        bits += bitss[byte]
    return bits


def bits_Kelly_2(a):
    bitss = [[]]
    for _ in range(8):
        bitss = [bits + [bit] for bits in bitss for bit in (0, 1)]
    bits = []
    for byte in a:
        bits += bitss[byte]
    return bits


bitss = [[]]
for _ in range(8):
    bitss = [bits + [bit] for bits in bitss for bit in (0, 1)]

def bits_Kelly_3(a):
    bitss_ = bitss
    bits = []
    for byte in a:
        bits += bitss_[byte]
    return bits


def bits_Kelly_4(a):
    i = int.from_bytes(bytes(a))
    s = f'{i:0{len(a)*8}b}'
    s = s.translate(s.maketrans('01', '\0\1'))
    return list(s.encode())


# Using unpackbits() from juanpa's answer
def bits_Kelly_juanpa(a):
    a = np.frombuffer(bytes(a), dtype=np.uint8)
    return list(np.unpackbits(a).tobytes())


def bits_sbottingota_1(l):
    l_expanded = []
    for n in l:
        l_expanded.extend(format(n, "08b"))
    return [int(n) for n in l_expanded]


def bits_sbottingota_2(l):
    l = map(lambda n: format(n, "08b"), l)
    return [int(item) for sublist in l for item in sublist]


def bits_sbottingota_3(l):
    return list(map(int, (b for num in l for b in format(num, "08b"))))


funcs = [bits_Kelly_1, bits_Kelly_2, bits_Kelly_3, bits_Kelly_4, bits_Kelly_juanpa, bits_sbottingota_1, bits_sbottingota_2, bits_sbottingota_3]

expect = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for f in funcs:
    result = f([0b00001111, 0b01010101, 0b11110000])
    print(result == expect or result, f.__name__)

a = os.urandom(10**5)

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} ms '
for _ in range(50):
    shuffle(funcs)
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: f(a), number=1)
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVZLjptAEN1GnKI0WdA4BIE9HlmWfIJsssnKY6HGNDNkoEF0MxnL8kmymU2yzxVyjJwm1R_A-CNFSTDCdFV116s_X7_XO_lY8dfXb63M3i9-vamzpipB5iXLJeRlXTXSrhzNEZLKXMh8KzpuySj3kZ6yZyPSUJ7in2WLxzbLCubYJW_LegdUAK87UiW6N7ETjuOkLIMklyL-wIpiF0eEeksH8FJEAStYryclrUnOpQ-Zu8-X4SI5uN4GsqqBHHKuIDwwMp3feZt-p9poVkos2UmmJKk5uhd6tzJq1krAiDdMtg3X5HN00wvoNoOaeECz8MaqtKzRqf8NfE3IuZWwFEUgoQ_R_zdnhPoK4n9Ae-qu2dhdMVh8f2lW_Kdhuu315qgBMydQqRqr3YKYJ_U8LaAgmKzaF4wjebI4YHr1PBFIdI8oqGREBCV9YnpN3DByfXDvw_vItUdZSAUWDIoyvq1SRpDnOG_hk8j5A7S8ptsnBZR4oKvnc0uR5grAM7-w5tQQw-6toQiI19qYBOuMNb0xPqRyV7MVclu0d3GOSHEG9dQLZGU2a4S9XpFUUiLWSlKsxcIqLmL2UmOhs3QcMa7CVQzhGuQC9iIZTwlKlRS1-3CDdXszdtUaoRLuHR3V799cAzUdQCEW1RkKWiYpBb6EU2U-FOf6cslKo1K0iXKNVmy6CbLUyjKuYpj1GI493HcpkhiL2nI4OlGvHb627N2hvZ-1fNuXXNcI_VHjGa1mo9Wtf54y_oVoXqBNL9BmaDZGgW2lQoSV3d_R0R1eeZ7I2Ns0m0z7QNnaOU-0hdKSkXWYhHhFeKF4Ekbmp94VTfE2JpR1o4LYbV2BhYrHGxoOiSCOOS1ZHKNvVclUImjNmCJROJnMkayGnPL4PltiPsMY3UFHXc0-QTIbaNOrJEwgYjMtr_NG4CBjKdHHrbONt17ON6MGhb1FjUwihbe8C6bZAX7-gL2en5p2q2mlAPe0H89Dq9rOVKKxeX3tnXpTo0SQZn7bqsCa0N0BUy5hzSryBlELOaB1rQpVekOMrFX6cB-e2G6lnWHxmAh07jnxt2G69_yj_tRYYpPEOR88s0bkFffMh4f9_ui-Q34D)

Answer (score 0):

Using Kelly's program I added a few variants of sbottingota

```py
def bits_sbottingota_4(l):
    table = [format(num, "08b") for num in range(256)]
    return list(map(int, (b for num in l for b in table[num])))

def bits_sbottingota_5(l):
    table = [list(map(int, format(num, "08b"))) for num in range(256)]
    result = []
    for b in l:
        result.extend(table[b])
    return result

def bits_sbottingota_5f(l):
    table = [list(map(int, f'{num:08b}')) for num in range(256)]
    result = []
    for b in l:
        result.extend(table[b])
    return result

bitstable = [list(map(int, format(num, "08b"))) for num in range(256)]

def bits_sbottingota_6(l):
    result = []
    for b in l:
        result.extend(bitstable[b])
    return result

def bits_sbottingota_7(l):
    result = []
    for b in l:
        result += bitstable[b]
    return result

def bits_juanpa_1(l):
    return [b for b in np.unpackbits(np.array(list(l), dtype=np.uint8))]

def bits_juanpa_2(l):
    return list(np.unpackbits(np.array(list(l), dtype=np.uint8)).tobytes())
```

The results on my machine (a bit slower than Kelly's)

The fast versions are 4 times slower, but the slow versions are about as fast as Kelly's

```
 12.91 ± 0.19 ms  bits_juanpa_2
 23.30 ± 0.35 ms  bits_Kelly_3
 23.59 ± 0.33 ms  bits_Kelly_2
 23.80 ± 0.20 ms  bits_Kelly_1
 24.38 ± 0.12 ms  bits_sbottingota_7
 25.50 ± 0.34 ms  bits_sbottingota_5f
 26.23 ± 0.10 ms  bits_sbottingota_5
 26.35 ± 0.31 ms  bits_sbottingota_6
 75.57 ± 0.43 ms  bits_juanpa_1
142.38 ± 0.75 ms  bits_sbottingota_4
170.92 ± 0.59 ms  bits_sbottingota_2
172.71 ± 0.62 ms  bits_sbottingota_3
184.91 ± 0.98 ms  bits_sbottingota_1
```

It is not the conversion from number to bits (`format()`) that takes most of the time but the manipulation of the lists.

The construction of the lookup table is a bit more clear using `list(map(int, format(num, "08b")))` then Kelly's method.

The f-strings are faster than `format()`.

I tried if creating a local ref to the lookup table makes things faster but it differs on several runs, so most likely it is negligible, just as the length of the local variable name. And Python already knows that `bitstable` is global because it uses a `LOAD_GLOBAL` instruction. It does not look in the locals first. The global dictionary is a big larger than the local dictionary and that could have a small influence in the lookup in case of name collision.

I am surprised that `list::+=` is faster than `list::extend` (see disassembly)

For an array of size 100'000 it does not matter if you pre-calculate the `bitstable` as a global variable

The numpy version (juanpa) is the fastest, if you know numpy (peeked at Kelly's code: `to_bytes()`)

---

Bytecode for `result.extend(bitstable[b])`:

```
 10          12 LOAD_FAST                1 (result)
             14 LOAD_METHOD              0 (extend)
             16 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (bitstable)
             18 LOAD_FAST                2 (b)
             20 BINARY_SUBSCR
             22 CALL_METHOD              1
             24 POP_TOP
```

Bytecode for `result += bitstable[b]`:

```
 16          12 LOAD_FAST                1 (result)
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (bitstable)
             16 LOAD_FAST                2 (b)
             18 BINARY_SUBSCR
             20 INPLACE_ADD
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (result)
```

Looks like `INPLACE_ADD` is faster for lists than `CALL_METHOD (extend)`, or it is the number of instructions 3 compared to 2.

Comment: Why surprised about `+=` being faster? It's equivalent to `extend` but has the advantage of being syntax and thus more specialized/direct bytecode/execution.

Comment: @KellyBundy I looked at the bytecode and the `+=` uses a different bytecode and number of instructions

Comment: If you use a local variable like I do in mine, it's not in a dictionary. It has a fixed index in an array. It should be significantly faster, and it is for me. What Python version/implementation are you using? Your times being so very different from mine is actually quite surprising.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I had tried local vs global and it was a large difference, but trying it again, it's indeed minor (the solution with local variable being ~5% faster). Not sure what I had done earlier.

Comment: Ooh, I think I know what it was. My earlier test with global wasn't intentional, I was accidentally using the wrong variable, and that was not only global but also a different data type, and the latter is what slowed it down a lot. Didn't realize that until now, thought it was just the globality.

Comment: @KellyBundy I use Python 3.8.5 64 bit Windows, the array index explains that the length of the local variable name (calc hash) is of no influence, the local var is always faster that global but there is so much variation between runs that most likely the other calculations are the bulk of the time taken and not the variable load, I have added juanpa's alternative

Comment: Ha, I also just integrated juanpa's, but in a faster way.